# How to control behavior for missing URL params in gin 1.4.0+?

Tags: go, url-routing, httphandler, go-gin

I'm working on migrating from `1.3.0` to `1.4.0` (or `1.5.0`) and I've discovered that `1.3.0` for the following snippet

```
router := gin.New()
router.GET("/func/:id/details", func(c *gin.Context) {
    value := c.Param("id")
    fmt.Printf("value is %v\n", value)
})
```

Would always get to the handler even when requesting `/func//details` (note the missing URL `param`) whereas `1.4.0` and above will return `404`.

Is it possible to control this behavior? (to work the same way as it worked in `1.3.0`?)

I've tried using [`BindUri`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.BindUri) introduced in `1.5.0`

```
func main() {
    type Params struct {
        ID string `uri:"id" binding:"required"`
    }
    router := gin.New()
    router.GET("/func/:id/details", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var pp Params
        if err := c.BindUri(&pp); err != nil {
            log.Errorf("failed binding: %v", err)
            c.Status(http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        log.Printf("params %+v\n", pp)
    })

    if err := router.Run("localhost:8080"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

But this also fails (with `404`) when called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem is the internal `cleanPath()` function with the following documentation:

> ...  The following rules are applied iteratively until no further
>   processing can  be done:
>
> 1. Replace multiple slashes with a single slash.
>
> [reference](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/59ab588bf597f9f41faee4f217b5659893c2e925/path.go#L13)

And if you checkout the latest master branch on Github there is a configuration called [RemoveExtraSlash](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/59ab588bf597f9f41faee4f217b5659893c2e925/gin.go#L141) and is false by default. The `RemoveExtraSlash` by default will not call `cleanPath()`[here](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/59ab588bf597f9f41faee4f217b5659893c2e925/gin.go#L394).

What I can see this was added Nov 28 and the latest commit for `1.5.0` was Nov 24.

What you can do is download the source from [GitHub](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin.git):

```
git clone https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin.git /home/user/projects/gin
```

Then do a replace at the end of your go.mod file. When there is a new release you can just remove the line:

```
replace github.com/gin-gonic/gin => /home/user/projects/gin
```

Comment: In the end this worked. I updated to https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/commit/352d69c71f45d51971f2d23f5c4450c6410aa481 and used the default value of `RemoveExtraSlash` (`false`) to keep my desired behavior.